# How to assign the result of json parsing to array variable

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to retrieve the list of currencies and store them in my variable.

That is the method, I'm requesting to server

```
func requestCurrencyRates(parseHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.fixer.io/latest")!

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (dataRecieved, response, error) in
        parseHandler(dataRecieved, error)
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Next, using jsonObject, I'm parsing my json, to get the array of currencies.

```
func parseCurrensyResponse(data: Data?) -> [String] {
    var currencies: [String] = [""]

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any>

        if let parsedJSON = json {
            //print("\(parsedJSON)")
            if let rates = parsedJSON["rates"] as? Dictionary<String, Double> {
                currencies = Array(rates.keys)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return currencies
}
```

After all, I wrote a wrapper method to retrieve currency

```
  func retrieveCurrency(comletion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        requestCurrencyRates { [unowned self] (data, error) in
            var currencies = [""]

            if error != nil {
                fatalError()
            } else {
                currencies = self.parseCurrensyResponse(data: data)
            }
            comletion(currencies)
        }
    }
```

However, when I'm trying to assign my variable the result of parsing, in log I still recieve an empty array

```
var currencies = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setCurrencies(currency: currencies)
    print(currencies)
    //log: []
}

func setCurrencies( currency: [String]) {
    var currency = currency
    retrieveCurrency { value in
        currency = value
    }
}
```

Further on, this array is need to be bind to picker.

Comment: You need to access the currencies inside the `retrieveCurrency` completionHandler.

Comment: But, don't I'm doing so in func setCurrencies? @NiravD

Comment: First of all you need to assign `currencies` in the `retrieveCurrency` block not the `currency`, After making this change you will still get empty array in viewDidLoad print because it will execute before your completionHandler of `retrieveCurrency`, so you need to perform any action that you want to perform on array goes inside that block.

Comment: @NiravD am I understand you right, about assigning currencies in the block? https://yadi.sk/i/1CDO3NoR3EKndA
And how can I perform action to go array inside the block? What should I do for that?

Comment: Simply reload your pickerView inside the completionHandler of `retrieveCurrency`.